# How would I take an input with python in discord.py?

Tags: python, input, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a game for my discord server and when someone says a command, for example !dice I want to take an input for how many coins they want to bet. I don't know how to take an input with discord, so if anyone knows that would be a huge help!

Comment: With Discord I've come across 3 ways: Clicking on emojis. Indicating the number inside a slash command. Or indicating the number after the command (!dice 1)

Comment: Thanks Gevorg. I've thought of making the bet after the command but I've come across 2 problems. Firstly, how would I take the actual bet considering if I said !dice 1 then I don't know how I could just take the 1, for the bet. Secondly, if the first problem is fixed I would have to make 200 individual if statements considering I only want you to be able to bet 200...

Comment: Try slash commands

Answer (score 0):

Just create a simple command. This one only sends the message with the amount of coins you write, but you can do something else with it:

```py
@client.command()
async def dice(ctx, value): # value variable will store user's input
    await ctx.send(f"You just bet {value} coins") # sends user's input
```

*Example usage:*
`<prefix>dice <amount>` - `!dice 200`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a command argument to get an 'input' for the command as suggested by @RiveN's answer.

Another way to get an input is by 'waiting for' the user to send a message as an input after the command was invoked. This can be done by using [`Bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for). Essentially what this method does is, it waits for a temporary Discord event under special conditions if specified.

```py
@client.command()
async def dice(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send("What value do you want to bet on?")
    message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda msg: msg.author == ctx.author, timeout=60.0)
    
    value_input = message.content
    ...
```

You can now do what you want to do with `value_input` since `message` is a [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message) object.

This is what the usage example looks like:

```yaml
User: !dice
Bot: What value do you want to bet on?
# Now the bot waits for 60 seconds for the user to send a message.
User: 2
# Now value_input(or message.content) is 2, and there you have the user input.
# The bot no longer waits for the event since the user sent a message.
```

Here is what happened in wait_for:

1. Create a temporary on_message event
2. Check if the message author is the command invoker
3. Specify a timeout so that if 60 seconds exceed, no longer wait for the event

You can read more here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for